# Citing arXiv version of an article

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Recently I was looking at an article on arXiv (2009) "*Bertini type theorems*" by Jing Zhang ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4105)). The email address of the author mentioned in the article seems no longer working. Can anyone let me know the email of the author? Since I have not seen any journal reference of the article, is it OK to use results from this article citing the arXiv version?

Comment: "OK to use results" --- well, arXiv is an unrefereed publication, so "OK" or "not OK" will depend on what use you have in mind.

Comment: I want to use the main result of this article to prove a certain statement. I do not understand whether I should rely on it or not.

Comment: it is not refereed, so this is fully your responsibility; I presume you will want to check the proof yourself, and if you are satisfied it can be trusted, use it, otherwise do not.

Comment: It looks like this may be the more current information for the author of the paper in question: https://www.govst.edu/Site_Navigation/Contact/Directory/jzhang/

Comment: A word of warning: as a referee, I would not accept a paper depending in an essential way of results of an unpublished preprint.

Comment: @abx Well, by that logic, you would not accept any paper, given that all papers are submitted to journals as unpublished preprints :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I not cite an arxiv.org paper which otherwise seems to be unpublished?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41141/should-i-not-cite-an-arxiv-org-paper-which-otherwise-seems-to-be-unpublished) See also [How reliable is arXiv to use as a reference in a paper?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/335245)

Comment: In my opinion, if you want to use in an essential way a result published in a preprint (and not already accepted for publication) you should add a proof. If the proof is the same as the one in the preprint, you should also write something like "We borrow this argument from..."

Comment: Why should one trust the stamp of approval by an anonymous referee for correctness more than the author who's track record you know? Many don't even think it's the referee's job to check correctness.

Comment: @VilleSalo: point taken, yet generally it is not just the "stamp of approval by an anonymous referee" which leads to the publication of an article, but also a "stamp of approval" from the named editorial board of the journal.